# Terraform not declaring tfvars

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, hcl

I am new to Terraform and I am writing a script. Following is my directory structure

```
folder
---.terraform
---..terraform.lock.hcl
---main.tf
---terraform.tfvars
---variables.tf
```

Following is my content on `terraform.tfvars`.

```
environment    = "development"
```

Following is my content on `main.tf`.

```
tags = {
  environment = var.environment
}
```

But the values are not updating. Following is the error:

```
╷
│ Warning: Value for undeclared variable
│
│ The root module does not declare a variable named "environment" but a value was found in file "terraform.tfvars". If you meant to use this value, add a "variable" block to the configuration.
│
│ To silence these warnings, use TF_VAR_... environment variables to provide certain "global" settings to all configurations in your organization. To reduce the verbosity of these warnings, use the      
│ -compact-warnings option.
╵
╷
│ Warning: Value for undeclared variable
│
│ The root module does not declare a variable named "admin_username" but a value was found in file "terraform.tfvars". If you meant to use this value, add a "variable" block to the configuration.        
│
│ To silence these warnings, use TF_VAR_... environment variables to provide certain "global" settings to all configurations in your organization. To reduce the verbosity of these warnings, use the      
│ -compact-warnings option.
╵
╷
│ Warning: Values for undeclared variables
│
│ In addition to the other similar warnings shown, 1 other variable(s) defined without being declared.
╵
╷
│ Error: Reference to undeclared input variable
│
│   on main.tf line 22, in resource "azurerm_resource_group" "tf_example_rg":
│   22:     environment = var.environment
│
│ An input variable with the name "environment" has not been declared. This variable can be declared with a variable "environment" {} block.
```

As I am using `terraform.tfvars` I don't need to give the filename on CLI. I think I am doing everything right but it's yet not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to actually declare your variable using [variable](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/values/variables) block. For example:

```
variable "environment" {}
```

If you have such declarations, you have to double check the spelling and locations of them.

Comment: @AunZaidi Before you can set value of a variable, you have to declare it. That's how TF works and you can't change that.

Comment: thanks, I had wrong understanding of the usage. I have edited the answer and added more to it.

Answer (score 1):

@AunZaidi , As stated in the error messages `terraform` can not find the defined variables.

`The root module does not declare a variable named "environment" but a value was found in file "terraform.tfvars". If you meant to use this value, add a "variable" block to the configuration.`

I would recommend you to take a look at the [terraform-azure-tutorials](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/tutorials/azure-get-started) to get acquainted with the basics.

you can solve your issue by just defining a new variable using syntax

```
variable "environment" {
  type        = string
  description = "(optional) Environment for the deployment"
}
```

Refer to https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/values/variables#arguments for definitions of the arguments used in terraform variables.

Also one of the recommended practices is to use a dedicated file `variables.tf` for all the variables inputs required in your terraform code.